# How to search over IMAP full text search?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am working on micro service where I have to implement full text search over IMAP server. We are storing the mails in documents. While implementing the full text search, it's taking too much time to connect to IMAP and server requests time out. I was using match() method which is available in IMAP.

```
@Override
public boolean match(Message message) {
    try {
        Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
        if (fromAddress != null && fromAddress.length > 0) {
            if (fromAddress[0].toString().contains(fromEmail)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
     
    return false;
}
```

I am using the following article as a reference (https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/using-javamail-for-searching-e-mail-messages).

This is taking too much time to search. Has anyone an idea about how to reduce the time and get results without loosing the connection?

Note: we have indexed our documents so we could search fast.

Comment: Avoid custom SearchTerm subclasses. Your code is not sent to the IMAP server for execution there. Use the [supplied search term subclasses](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.html) instead, those are sent to the server and are generally executed quickly by it.

Comment: I have also tried it. But it is taking too much time. It processes almost 600 records in 1 minute. so we have switched to solr Server for searching the data. Its extremely fast for any number of records.

Answer (score 0):

So, after roaming around all over the Internet I find out that IMAP is not a good idea to use for searching in large amount of data. I could search 600-800 records per minute. But it's not very much fast and unable to fulfil my need.

So to search over large amount of data we have switched to Solr Server. which is extremely fast.
[Apache Solr Server](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_3/about-this-guide.html). To connect with Java it has a client library SolrJ.

```
>   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But you can't use actuator dependency and solrJ at the same time. you need to provide configurations explicitly for that.